# Ruby How to delete element from array and return new instance of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zendesk

I'm dealing with this caveat:

https://github.com/zendesk/zendesk_api_client_rb#caveats

they have an example of adding a new element to the `tags` array and creating a new instance which trigger the `changed?` state.

I need to remove an element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the same technique they used, but with the `-=` operator.

```
>> a = []
=> []
>> a.object_id
=> 2154250660
>> a << 'hello'
=> ["hello"]
>> a.object_id
=> 2154250660
>> a += ['hi']
=> ["hello", "hi"]
>> a.object_id
=> 2154228260
>> a -= ['hi']
=> ["hello"]
>> a.object_id
=> 2154204700
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried:

```
a -= [element]
```